# Can rpmbuild command build only 1 subpackage?

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, specifications

I have 1 spec file: bla.spec and it builds 1.rpm and 2.rpm.
Can I build only subpackage - 2.rpm?

Answer (score -2):

Depends. Not usually, because if you don't specify packages for every file you leave in the target area, that's an error. You could always delete the files in your build process, but it's just as easy IMHO to erase `1.rpm` when it's all done.